# Recuperar JSON no PHP

Tags: php, json

Vi muitos fóruns mas ainda não resolveu pra mim

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <label for="banco">Banco</label>
  <select id="banco" type="number" class="form-control" required="" >
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value='{"sigla" : "bradesco", "banco": "Bradesco"}'>Bradesco</option>
    <option value='{"sigla" : "bb", "bank": "Brasil"}'>Brasil</option>
    <option value='{"sigla" : "cef", "bank": "Caixa Economica Federal"}'>Caixa Econ&ocirc;mica Federal</option>
    <option value='{"sigla" : "itau", "bank": "Itau"}'>Ita&uacute;</option>
    <option value='{"sigla" : "santander_banespa", "bank": "Santander"}'>Santander</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

Tenho no JavaScript que faz o seguinte envio:

```
function salvar(){
jQuery('#form').submit(function () {
    var banco       = document.getElementById('banco').value;
     $.ajax({
     type    : 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     url     : 'function/conta.php',
     beforeSend : carregando,
     data: {                
           'banco'      : JSON.stringify(banco),         
           },
           success: function (data) {
           //alert(data.retorno);
           if (data.retorno == 1) {
           sucesso('Opera&ccedil;&atilde;o realizada com sucesso!');
           }
           else {
           errosend('N&atilde;o foi poss&iacute;vel realizar opera&ccedil;&atilde;o. Verifique se todos os campos est&atilde;o preenchidos ');
          }
        }
      });
    return false; 
 });
}
```

**PHP**

No PHP ele retorna:

```
if(isset($_POST['banco'])){
    $banco = $_POST['banco'];
}

$bank1 = json_decode($banco);

foreach ($bank1 as $item => $value) {
        echo $value->{'bank'};
    }
```

Porém a mensagem que dá é:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Cada caso é um caso, pois em outro arquivo que uso esse bloco *foreach* funciona rs

Comment: Faz um teste pra ver que tipo de dados retorna. Coloca antes do `foreach` assim: var_dump($bank); ... coloca aqui oque está exibindo a você.

Comment: Certeza que o JS está gerando o JSON com aspas simples? Fiz um [teste](https://repl.it/Ge2Y/0) aqui e retornou com aspas duplas e, deste modo, funcionou perfeitamente no [PHP](https://repl.it/Ge2V/0).

Comment: Gerou isso aqui `{'sigla' : 'bb', 'bank': 'Brasil'}' (length=34)`

Comment: Testei no PHP e com aspas simples não funciona. Quando coloco aspas duplas ele funciona como deveria. A função do jQuery/Javascript está gerando corretamente o JSON ?

Comment: editei para ver se fica melhor compreensiva a pergunta

Comment: ele falou em php e não jquery. Eu não posso responder, mais essa é uma boa formas, veja uma api de cotação como exemplo: <?php 
$json_str = file_get_contents("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all/USD-BRL,EUR-BRL");   
$jsonObj = json_decode($json_str);
$usd = $jsonObj->USD;
$eur = $jsonObj->EUR;
 ?>                                                                                                                                                     depois você apenas recupera com echo {{ $eur->ask }}, isso mostra a cotação atual, agora basta adaptar a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer o que você precisa, mas vou usando o seu conceito.

No **Javascript** tente enviar o conteúdo do `option` selecionado como ele é:

```
function salvar(){
jQuery('#form').submit(function () {
    var banco       = document.getElementById('banco').value;
     $.ajax({
                type    : 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url     : 'function/conta.php',
                beforeSend : carregando,
                data: {

                    'banco'      : banco,

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data.retorno);
                    if (data.retorno == 1) {
                        sucesso('Opera&ccedil;&atilde;o realizada com sucesso!');
                    }
                     else {
                        errosend('N&atilde;o foi poss&iacute;vel realizar opera&ccedil;&atilde;o. Verifique se todos os campos est&atilde;o preenchidos ');
                    }
                }
              });
        return false; 
});
}
```

No PHP decodifique com o `json_encode`

```
if(isset($_POST['banco'])){
    $banco = $_POST['banco'];
}

$bank1 = json_decode($banco);

echo $bank1->sigla.'<br />';
echo $bank1->bank;
```

> O erro que pelo que percebi, é que o seu `option` está enviando um
>   objeto único e não um array de objetos, sendo assim, não precisa ser
>   pego (e nem vai dar) pelo `foreach` que apenas faz um loop com arrays.
>   Com isso, você pode pegar o objeto diretamente.

OBS: Percebi que no seus `options` tem um valor do json que se chama **banco** ao invés de **bank**.. Cuidado com isso, pois pode dar erros futuros nas verificações.

Comment: deu isso aqui `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ` mas se seu der var_dump os dados mostram

Comment: Dê um var_dump($bank1); antes do `foreach` e posta o que retorna

Comment: retorna isso aqui `object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'sigla' => string 'bb' (length=2)
  public 'bank' => string 'Brasil' (length=6)
`

Comment: @adventistaam editei a resposta, da uma olhada lá

Comment: Bingo!!! Era exatamente isso! Deu certo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Então eu nao precisava usar o JSON.stringify

Comment: @adventistaam de nada ;)

Comment: @adventistaam não, porque no `option` você está enviando já um json em forma de string. No PHP é só decodificar ele.

Comment: Valeu mesmo! Tenho que aprender muito

Comment: @adventistaam estamos sempre na fase de aprendizagem rsrs. Qualquer coisa, só postar aqui no Stack OverFlow que algum de nós ajudaremos você.

Comment: Blz. Pode deixar